# Console-Setup does not configure

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, upgrade, debian-jessie

I want to upgrade debian wheezy to jessie. But the program console-setup has problems with its configuration script.

I cancelled the upgrade process and started the configuration manual:

```
dpkg --configure -D2  console-setup
console-setup (1.123) wird eingerichtet ...
```

This script never ends.
I edited this script(/var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.postinst) because of this line:

```
dpkg --configure -D2  console-setup
console-setup (1.123) wird eingerichtet ...
--> D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.postinst ( configure 1.88 )
```

I added this line: set -ex

Now I get this result:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.postinst
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ !  ]
+ PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1
+ export PERL_DL_NONLAZY
+ [  ]
+ exec /usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.postinst
Use of uninitialized value $action in string eq at /usr/share/debconf/frontend line 27.
+ . /usr/share/debconf/confmodule
+ [ ! 1 ]
+ [ -z  ]
+ exec
+ [  ]
+ exec
+ DEBCONF_REDIR=1
+ export DEBCONF_REDIR
+ CONFIGDIR=/etc/console-setup
+ CONFIGFILE=/etc/default/console-setup
+ [ ! -L /usr/share/doc/console-setup ]
+ [  = configure -a ! -L /etc/default/console-setup ]
+ setupcon --save-only
+ setupcon
```

The script does not end!

Do you know why this script does not work?

Thy for your help!